# vba selenium get compound class names not permitted during find element by class

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, class, button

I am using this coding

Chromedrive.FindElementByClass("sc-gbzWSY fwFVCo").Click

and inspect body is

```
<button class="sc-gbzWSY fwFVCo">
"Upload Template File"
input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" 
class="sc-ecaExY kUneBm">
</button>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWjgU.png)

AND I GOT ERROR

COMPUND CLASS NAMES NOT PERMITTED

plz give solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't go by Class as Class seems a dynamic one. Use the XPath below

```
//button[contains(.'Upload Template File')]
```